# The use of preposition "on" in context

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please If I used the preposition on correctly in the following sentence.

> What days do you like to go out **on**? Personally, I like to go out on Wednesday.

What if I asked the following question,

> When do you like to go out.

Would it be the same question.

Comment: Go out is general. You don't need on.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of the preposition **on** is fine there, as for your second question the answer is **no**. **"When do you like to go out?"** Isn't as specific as **"Which days of the week do like to go out on?"** One question asks for specific days of the week, the other one isn't specific at all.

Answer (score 0):

When do you like to go out?

The question could be asking about time, weekday, night/daytime/dawn/dusk, before/after an activity, etc.

Also, the first question asks "What days do ...?" I think the answer would be "Wednesday**s**"